# Why do I get a RefrenceError that my function is not defined?

Tags: html, reactjs, error-handling

I want to make a file with many directories such as:

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
  <head>
    <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1.0">
    <script src="App.js"></script>
  </head>
  <body>
    <h1>To-do List</h1>
    <input type="text" name="addTask" id="addTask" placeholder="Add a new task!">
    <div id="toDoContainer"></div>
    <input type="button" id='button' value="Add task" onclick="app()">
  </body>
</html>
```

and then running `app()` from App.js:

```
import React from "react";
import ReactDOM from 'react-dom/client';
import CheckTask from "./Check.js";

const app = () => {
  const toDoList = document.getElementById('toDoContainer');
  const root = ReactDOM.createRoot(toDoList);
  root.render(<CheckTask />);
}


export default app;
```

and then lastly getting the `CheckTask` component from Check.js:

```
import React from "react";
import ReactDOM from 'react-dom/client';
 
 const CheckTask = () => {
    let input = document.getElementById('addTask').value
         if (input === ''||input === ' ') {
              return alert('You have to write something')           
         } else {
          const toDoList = document.getElementById('toDoContainer');
          const root = ReactDOM.createRoot(toDoList);
            return (root.render(<h1>Hello World</h1>))
         }
}

export default CheckTask;
```

But, I always get this error message when pressing the button:

```
Uncaught runtime errors:
ERROR
the app is not defined
ReferenceError: app is not defined
    at HTMLInputElement.onclick (http://localhost:3002/:11:71)
```

I checked on Google and it says it is either a variable out of scope or not declared properly, but I don't see any problems with those:

Full source code:

index.html

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
  <head>
    <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1.0">
    <script src="App.js"></script>
  </head>
  <body>
    <h1>To-do List</h1>
    <input type="text" name="addTask" id="addTask" placeholder="Add a new task!">
    <div id="toDoContainer"></div>
    <input type="button" id='button' value="Add task" onclick="app()">
  </body>
</html>
```

App.js

```
import React from "react";
import ReactDOM from 'react-dom/client';
import CheckTask from "./Check.js";

const app = () => {
  const toDoList = document.getElementById('toDoContainer');
  const root = ReactDOM.createRoot(toDoList);
  root.render(<CheckTask />);
}


export default app;
```

Check.js

```
import React from "react";
import ReactDOM from 'react-dom/client';
 
 const CheckTask = () => {
    let input = document.getElementById('addTask').value
         if (input === ''||input === ' ') {
              return alert('You have to write something')           
         } else {
          const toDoList = document.getElementById('toDoContainer');
          const root = ReactDOM.createRoot(toDoList);
            return (root.render(<h1>Hello World</h1>))
         }
}

export default CheckTask;
```

What is causing this problem?

Answer (score 0):

This error is causing because of how how module bundlers and the ES6 import/export system work. `app` function defined in `App.js` is not accessible in the global scope.

By including `App.js` as a module in you HTML file and setting up an event listener in javascript you can get this done. You should also remove `onclick` in HTML.

In `index.html`, script tag should be like follow,

```html
<script type="module" src="App.js"></script>
```

Then the `input` should be as follows

```html
<input type="button" id='button' value="Add task">
```

Then in `App.js`, you would export app and set up the event listener after the page loads:

```js
import React from "react";
import ReactDOM from 'react-dom/client';
import CheckTask from "./Check.js";

export const app = () => {
  const toDoList = document.getElementById('toDoContainer');
  const root = ReactDOM.createRoot(toDoList);
  root.render(<CheckTask />);
};

document.addEventListener('DOMContentLoaded', (event) => {
  document.getElementById('button').addEventListener('click', app);
});
```